# Is My Linux Server online?

Tags: server

I've installed a local server at work because I want to be have a staff "Instruction Manual" running off of a MediaWiki server. I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 and just installed Apache2, MySQL, and PHP7.0.

I only want this to be available locally so that staff can access it on our private network, so I want to make sure it's not available online. Is there any way I can test this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the server have a public IP address, i. e. outside of the subnets listed in m_krisc's answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are behind a router the ports shouldn't forward unless you specifically set them to, and you should be fine. (Apache's default is port 80) To be certain, just google "what is my ip address" and then attempt to access that IP from a device outside the network (a phone over LTE should work nicely).

Comment: Thank you! I tried that and it's inaccessible from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

`ifconfig` will tell you the IP of the server.

If the server is running on a machine that can be accessed from the internet then it is quite possible that it is visible to the internet.

If the IP is not inside one of these ranges then it is a public IP and a firewall will be needed to block incoming connections. If the IP is outside of these ranges you can try opening a broswer and going to that IP.

```
    10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255   
    172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255 
    192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255
```

If the IP of the server is in one of these ranges it ultimately depends on your network setup, if incoming connections are allowed at the router, if there is port forwarding etc.

While working on figuring this out, DO NOT  post IP of this server anywhere on any question forum if it is outside of the ranges listed above.